# What is the correct format for datetime object with this string in python datetime library? "2023-12-06T21:54:00+0000"

Tags: python, datetime

All I want to do is to make a datetime object with the string below, but it still gives me this error.

```
ValueError: time data '2023-12-06T21:54:00+0000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'
```

my code

```
enter_time = "2023-12-06T21:54:00+0000"

datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(enter_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')

time = datetime_obj.time()

print(time)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an ISO8601 datetime, so `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(...)`

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> enter_time = "2023-12-06T21:54:00+0000"
>>> datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(enter_time)
>>> time = datetime_obj.time()
>>> print(time)
21:54:00
```